# How to integrate the function $f(x,y,z)=yz$ over the part of the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4$ that lies above the cone $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I know this is a question related to surface integral. What I am confused about is that the question gives a region that has volume instead of a surface. And I guess what the question really means is that we only need to care about the very top slice surface of the sphere. If that is correct, I found it hard to parametrize that surface because of the cone.
Can someone help me with this?
Thanks!

Comment: The question gives a part of the sphere, a surface. For its parameterization you can use spherical coordinates: $r=2$, one angle will be between $0$ and $2\pi$ and the other between $\tfrac{\pi}{4}$ and $\tfrac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: I think the other angle is between 0 and $π/4$